# Parentheses control

Tags: formatting, latex, education, boxes, matex

I have an equation with random integer coefficients. The structure is to demonstrate the distributive property.

```
{a, b, c, d} = RandomInteger[{1, 9}, 4];
Row[{TraditionalForm[a f[x] (b g[x] + c h[x])], " = ",TraditionalForm[Expand[a f[x] (b g[x] + c h[x])]]}]
```

I would like the parentheses surrounding the sum on the LHS to be slightly bigger to give is a more professional appearance. I've tried getting the inline Tex to work and I did find a discussion about using nudge right to do it. Is there a straightforward way to control the size of parentheses?

Comment: If you want it to use in the document to give away or in a demonstration, the most simple way is to select one of the parentheses in question, go to Menu/Format/Size, and select, say, 16. Then do the same with the second one. If you want it to work in a usual working file where you make your calculation, I think the task is too complex and will not pay off.

Comment: The title is a bit ambiguous, for future users looking for a similar question, a possible modification could be "How to change the size/style of parentheses"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off a side comment. I think you'll get something more professional right off the bat by avoiding the row and just putting the whole expression/equation inside TraditionalForm (note the `==`, but TraditionalForm will display it as a single equation symbol):

```
TraditionalForm[a f[x] (b g[x] + c h[x]) == Expand[a f[x] (b g[x] + c h[x])]]
```

Second, I don't think these particular forms allow control of the various box options/behavior explicitly. However, you can force things to happen by adding semantically irrelevant things. So, for example, you could add an invisible space that was styled to be slightly larger than the nearby text:

```
TraditionalForm[a f[x] (Style["\[InvisibleSpace]", 24] b g[x] + c h[x]) == Expand[a f[x] (b g[x] + c h[x])]]
```

The trick would be to figure out how to do this programmatically. How many of these will you need to do? Maybe you want to build your own `Parenthesize[...]` function that adds such things recursively for nested `Parenthesize` expressions.

Comment: That is an awesome trick using the invisibility of "*" and creating an invisible tower of nothing to force the bracket to be larger

Comment: It seem like one does not have to multiply both terms by `Style["\[InvisibleSpace]", 24]`, it suffices to multiply one term. In that case one can use a replacement rule to make the substitution automatically for a particular structure. For example: `p + a f[x] (b g[x] + c h[x] + b*r[x]) /. 
 c_*(j_ + t_) :> c*(Style["", 24]*j + t)`

Comment: Yes, you only need one "tall" thing. I was playing around with where it would be most convenient, and apparently didn't clean up the other one.

Comment: And "as for this particular structure", yeah, we need to know how many cases the OP needs to handle.

Comment: I am having trouble imagining a case where my last update to the replacement rule would not work.

Comment: Oh, I see your update now. Yeah, that's when we'd expect parentheses. But that might not always require taller parentheses. One of the parentheses in the OP's case was actually function application. But maybe that doesn't matter--don't know OP's exact requirements. And I'm also just being conservative because I haven't sat down and tried to think through all cases.

Comment: Yeah for example making all the parenthesis large for  `p + a f[x]*(r + n) (b g[x] + c h[x] + b*r[x])^2*(k + d)` does not seem easy to do without defining an auxiliary function that checks Style["", 24]* to know whether it should do something and then use `FixedPoint` maybe

Answer (score 2):

A solution using Mathematica Boxes :

**Note**: One can copy expressions as LaTex in a Mathematica notebook but that does not seem to work with the method below.

Testing on a generic expression (my notebook already uses a large font so maybe the image below might look different on your notebook ):

```
p + a f[x]*(r + n) (b g[x] + c h[x] + b*r[x])^2*(k + d) // ToBoxes // 
ReplaceAll[{"(" -> Style["(", 30], ")" -> Style[")", 30]}] // 
DisplayForm // TraditionalForm
```

[image: expression_big_parenthesis]

Making a function BIGparenthesis:

```
BIGparenthesis[size_][s_] := 
s // ToBoxes // 
ReplaceAll[{"(" -> Style["(", size], ")" -> Style[")", size]}] //
DisplayForm // TraditionalForm;
```

Using it for OP's case :

```
{a, b, c, d} = RandomInteger[{1, 9}, 4]; 
BIGparenthesis[30][a f[x] (b g[x] + c h[x])] == 
BIGparenthesis[30][
Expand[a f[x] (b g[x] + c h[x])]] // TraditionalForm
```

[image: OP_example]